# In Class Table Inheritance, how to have parent and child use the same id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, activerecord, class-table-inheritance

I am having two classes: `Topic` and `Buy::Topic`. The latter is a sub class of the former, through a foreign key (`Buy::Topic.topic_id == Topic.id`). So essentially this is using **class table inheritance** pattern.

`Buy::Topic` has its own `id` and the foreign key `topic_id` pointing to the parent `Topic` object.

However I would like to make sure the id of `Buy::Topic` to be the same as the `topic_id` from the parent like this:

`#<Topic id: 22598>` with 
`#<Buy::Topic id: 22598, topic_id:22598`

Is this possible in Rails? This is better for SEO purposes, and will make it easier in dealing with Cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` (sometimes cancan use the wrong id of the two to find stuffs).

*UDPATE:*

This schema has been set and done for a long time, so it's unlikely to change it to STI now.

Comment: It feels like STI would be a better choice if you want the id's to match up.  You can always define the Buy::Topic to be a special case of Topic...

Comment: yeah I thought about it, and the reason is that the sub class has too many other fields.

Comment: ...and that's bad because?  To quote Knuth "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  Storage space is ridiculously cheap.  If your core requirement is "let the id's be the same" for SEO, then optimize for that, not for storage.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this will actively destroy your CTI and might even create an anti-pattern!

My argument is that if,

```
Buy::Topic.id == Buy::Topic.topic_id == Topic.id
```

then you create a one-to-one relationship between Buy::Topic and Topic.

This means that no other class can be composed of `Buy::Topic` because the `id` could clash with some `Topic.id`.

Since `Buy::Topic` is a subclass of `Topic`, you really only have a single conceptual entity now. Except you have two tables and some crazy indexes to get you there.

Comment: Yes, it is a one-to-one relationship. I don't get the clash part of the argument.

Comment: CTI is generally used to basically emulate composition for relational databases. ie: You have an individual and an organization, both of which have common address-related fields. You can then make a contact table which can be linked to by both of them. This feature is lost, making `Buy::Topic` only usable by `Topic`. See more here: http://laughingmeme.org/2004/08/14/mysql-and-the-case-for-class-table-inheritance/

Comment: Well, Buy::Topic is some extension to Topic, so it makes no sense to have Buy::Topic not belonging to Topic. And since this has been done and set before i started to maintain it, I won't be changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, this is okay, just call your column topic_parent_id and create association like this:

belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Topic', :foreign_key => 'topic_parent_id'